# Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [type:Factory,primary_type

Tags: android, mvvm, fragment, android-viewmodel, koin

I am developing news app I have implemented koin with viewmodel in fragment class but I am getting following error when I test code on emulator

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:557)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922) 
     Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [type:Factory,primary_type:'yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.viewmodel.MainViewModel']
        at org.koin.core.instance.DefinitionInstance.create(DefinitionInstance.kt:61)
        at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryDefinitionInstance.get(FactoryDefinitionInstance.kt:37)
        at org.koin.core.definition.BeanDefinition.resolveInstance(BeanDefinition.kt:70)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:165)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:128)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ViewModelResolutionKt$createViewModelProvider$1.create(ViewModelResolution.kt:66)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ViewModelResolutionKt.getInstance(ViewModelResolution.kt:43)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ViewModelResolutionKt.getViewModel(ViewModelResolution.kt:23)
        at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.LifecycleOwnerExtKt.getViewModel(LifecycleOwnerExt.kt:85)
        at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.ui.TopHeadlinesFragment$$special$$inlined$viewModel$1.invoke(LifecycleOwnerExt.kt:95)
        at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.ui.TopHeadlinesFragment$$special$$inlined$viewModel$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.ui.TopHeadlinesFragment.getViewModel(Unknown Source:7)
        at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.ui.TopHeadlinesFragment.initViewModel(TopHeadlinesFragment.kt:57)
        at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.ui.TopHeadlinesFragment.onCreateView(TopHeadlinesFragment.kt:51)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1392)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7252)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3000)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:185)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:170)
2019-11-16 15:12:01.728 12995-12995/yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:147)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
            ... 3 more
     Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for 'java.lang.Object' has been found. Check your module definitions.
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.findDefinition(Scope.kt:170)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:164)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:128)
        at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.di.application.module.AppModulesKt$appModules$1$3.invoke(appModules.kt:65)
        at yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.di.application.module.AppModulesKt$appModules$1$3.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at org.koin.core.instance.DefinitionInstance.create(DefinitionInstance.kt:54)
            ... 44 more
```

below TopHeadlinesFragment.kt

class TopHeadlinesFragment : Fragment() {

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModel()
private lateinit var topHeadlinesAdapter: TopHeadlinesAdapter


//3
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.fragment_top_headlines
        , container, false
    )


    val recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
    val pb = view.findViewById(R.id.pb) as ProgressBar
    topHeadlinesAdapter = TopHeadlinesAdapter(recyclerView.context)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.adapter = topHeadlinesAdapter
    initViewModel()

    return view
}

private fun initViewModel() {
    viewModel?.sportList?.observe(this, Observer { newList ->
        topHeadlinesAdapter.updateData(newList)
    })

    viewModel?.showLoading?.observe(this, Observer { showLoading ->
        pb.visibility = if (showLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    })

    viewModel?.showError?.observe(this, Observer { showError ->
        (showError)
    })

    viewModel?.loadNews()
}
```

}

below MainViewModel.kt

```
Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class MainViewModel(newsRepository: Any?) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    // Coroutine's background job
     val job = Job()
     val sportNewsInterface: SportNewsInterface? = null
    // Define default thread for Coroutine as Main and add job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

     val showLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
     val sportList = MutableLiveData <List<Article>>()
    val showError = SingleLiveEvent<String>()



    fun loadNews(

    ) {
        // Show progressBar during the operation on the MAIN (default) thread
        showLoading.value = true
        // launch the Coroutine
        launch {
            // Switching from MAIN to IO thread for API operation
            // Update our data list with the new one from API
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                sportNewsInterface?.getNews()
            }
            // Hide progressBar once the operation is done on the MAIN (default) thread
            showLoading.value = false
            when (result) {

                is UseCaseResult.Success<*> -> {
                    sportList.value = result.data as List<Article>
                }
                is Error -> showError.value = result.message
            }
        }


    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        // Clear our job when the linked activity is destroyed to avoid memory leaks
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

below appModules.kt

```
const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"

val appModules = module {
    // The Retrofit service using our custom HTTP client instance as a singleton
    single {
        createWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = BASE_URL
        )
    }
    // Tells Koin how to create an instance of CatRepository
    factory<NewsRepository> { (NewsRepositoryImpl(sportNewsInterface = get())) }
    // Specific viewModel pattern to tell Koin how to build MainViewModel
    viewModel { MainViewModel (newsRepository = get ())  }
}

/* Returns a custom OkHttpClient instance with interceptor. Used for building Retrofit service */
fun createHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    client.readTimeout(5 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    return client.addInterceptor {
        val original = it.request()
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        val request = requestBuilder.method(original.method, original.body).build()
        return@addInterceptor it.proceed(request)
    }.build()
}

/* function to build our Retrofit service */
inline fun <reified T> createWebService(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    factory: CallAdapter.Factory, baseUrl: String
): T {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(factory)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
}
```

below NewsRepository.kt where I have implemented NewsRepository

```
interface NewsRepository {
    // Suspend is used to await the result from Deferred
    suspend fun getNewsList(): UseCaseResult<Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>>
}

class NewsRepositoryImpl(private val sportNewsInterface: SportNewsInterface) : NewsRepository {
    override suspend fun getNewsList(): UseCaseResult<Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>> {
        /*
         We try to return a list of cats from the API
         Await the result from web service and then return it, catching any error from API
         */
        return try {
            val result = sportNewsInterface.getNews()
            UseCaseResult.Success(result) as UseCaseResult<Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>>
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            UseCaseResult.Error(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> class MainViewModel(newsRepository: Any?) : ViewModel(),
> CoroutineScope {

Why your `newsRepository` is of Any? type make it of `NewsRepository`

```
class MainViewModel(newsRepository: NewsRepository) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
```

In app module your `NewsRepositoryImpl` need's Implementation of `SportNewsInterface`.

I believe below is missing in your appModule.

```
factory<SportNewsInterface> { (SportNewsInterfaceImpl()) }
```

i.e:

```
val appModules = module {
        // The Retrofit service using our custom HTTP client instance as a singleton
        single {
            createWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
                okHttpClient = createHttpClient(),
                factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
                baseUrl = BASE_URL
            )
        }
        // Tells Koin how to create an instance of CatRepository
        factory<NewsRepository> { (NewsRepositoryImpl(sportNewsInterface = get())) }

        //Tells Koin how to create SportNewsInterface
        factory<SportNewsInterface> { (SportNewsInterfaceImpl()) }

        // Specific viewModel pattern to tell Koin how to build MainViewModel
        viewModel { MainViewModel (newsRepository = get ())  }
    }
```

Few other Tip's to clean up your code:

#### Use ViewModelScope instead of creating your own CoroutineScope in ViewModel

**dependency**

```
//Coroutine View Model Scope.
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0"
```

Comment: I dont understand this line of your code where exactly I have to implement this factory<SportNewsInterface> { (SportNewsInterfaceImpl()) }

Comment: @sashabeliy just like you did for     `factory<NewsRepository> { (NewsRepositoryImpl(sportNewsInterface = get())) }` 
to get NewsRepository you will have to define factory<SportNewsInterface> { (SportNewsInterfaceImpl()) }
in your AppModule

Comment: where you getting SportNewsInterfaceImpl I dont have such kinda of class I think it is irrelevant here

Comment: your `NewsRepositoryImpl` constructor need's a implementation of `SportNewsInterface` that is what u need to construct using koin

@sashabeliy

Comment: what do you think about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136748/recyclerview-not-showing-data

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have fixed it adding a `/`.
I changed from

```
single(named("baseUrl")) { "https://yourwebsite.net/api" }
```

to

```
single(named("baseUrl")) { "https://yourwebsite.net/api/" }
```

Comment: both lines are same bruh

Comment: Hi @eyurdakul, there is a small different, the final "/"

Comment: oh i see it now

Comment: technically those lines are still the same, since you're providing string value in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "provide" convention just like with Dagger @Provides annotation like in the example below.

```
val appModules = module {

    fun provideNewsRepository(sportNewsInterface: SportNewsInterface): NewsRepository {

        return NewsRepositoryImpl(sportNewsInterface)
    }

    fun provideSportNewsInterface(): SportNewsInterface {
        return createWebService < SportNewsInterface > (
            okHttpClient = createHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = BASE_URL
        )
    }

    single {
        provideNewsRepository(get())
    }
    single {
        provideSportNewsInterface()
    }
    viewModel {
        MainViewModel(newsRepository = get())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to create an instance of the API interface in the networking module.
My networking module class looks like this,

```
val networkingModule = module {
    single { GsonConverterFactory.create() as Converter.Factory }
    single { HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY) as Interceptor }
    single {
        OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) addInterceptor(get())
                .callTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }.build()
    }
    single {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.HOST)
            .client(get())
            .addConverterFactory(get())
            .build()
    }
    single { get<Retrofit>().create(LoginService::class.java) }
    single { get<Retrofit>().create(BlockService::class.java) }
    single { get<Retrofit>().create(ForgotPasswordService::class.java) }
}
```